# Mavericks won't update. Crash on boot software update

Tags: macos, software-update

I believe the update process was interrupted once. My computer works fine but the **SoftwareUpdateLauncher** fails to do anything on shutdown when I am logged out. I can see that it is in the application **SoftwareUpdateLauncher** but nothing happens, I've let it sit for over an hour before.

OS X 10.9.1

Photos:

- http://see.kirkstrobeck.com/UGoR
- http://see.kirkstrobeck.com/UGra
- http://see.kirkstrobeck.com/UH6o

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the software update caches at

```
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate
/Library/Caches/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate
```

Delete the entire folder you find.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work :(

Answer (score -1):

Dead easy. On the grey screen with softwareupdatelauncher just hit enter.